# Android flavor uses different drawables for mobile and tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-drawable, android-productflavors

I have an app that has multiple flavors. Each flavor contains Manifest with:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_2"
```

inside application tag. Each flavor has it's own ic_launcher_2 drawable with mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi sizes and all flavors works fine except one. XML of few screens has:

```
android:src="@drawable/log_login_screen"
```

inside ImageView tag and each flavor has it's own log_login_screen drawable in all sizes.

If i run the app on mobile, everything works fine, launcher is the one that  should be and also all the logos inside the app, but if I run it on tablet, it uses different ones. That's the case for only one flavor, all the other ones are ok... Maybe the issue is with drawable sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have issue with one/few drawables in the specific flavour.
try to recrate them or replace them with drawables from another flavour just to make sure that this is the issue

Comment: Yes, that was the case...thank you for the quick tip!